# Creating a custom Inspector in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a custom Inspector. Even if I change the values in the custom inspector, the values are being reset automatically.

Following is my Custom Inspector,

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(MovePlayer))]
public class CustomInspector : Editor
{
    
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        MovePlayer move = (MovePlayer) target;
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("ISpeed: ");
        move.speed = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(move.speed);
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal(); 
    }
}
```

The MovePlayer class implements `MonoBehavior` and `IMovePlayer`

```
public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour, IMovePlayer
{
    public float speed { set; get; } = 2f;

}
```

The interface is as follows,

```
public interface IMovePlayer
{
   
    float speed { set; get; }
}
```

Unfortunately, the values are being reset everytime even if I change the values in the Inspector. what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Speed is a property not a field. Try changing:

```
 public float speed { set; get; } = 2f;
```

to

```
public float _speed = 2f;
public float speed { 
     set { _speed = value; }
     get => _speed; 
}
```

Comment: @Thomash Finch it was a typo sorry :) still the error persists :(

Comment: Ah I think it's because speed is a property not a field. Try changing:

     public float speed { set; get; } = 2f;

to 
   
    public float _speed = 2f;
    public float speed { 
         set { _speed = value; }
         get => _speed; 
    }